# Is Tahoma a default font-type for certain HTML elements? (Mystery type coming from nowhere...)

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, autocomplete

This thing really bugs me: on http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/, how come the text in the autocomplete fields is in type face "Tahoma", even though it's not defined anywhere in the CSS?

Is it some kind of default font for certain HTML elements?!

(If it's relevant, I'm using Windows and tested that on Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you look at the `jquery.autocomplete.css` file on line 17, it sets the font to `menu`.

```
.ac_results li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: +1 And the default menu UI font on Windows XP, or Windows Vista/7 with the Classic theme, is Tahoma.

Comment: It's "Segoe UI" for Windows 7 / Aero theme. I was confused at first because it wasn't Tahoma for me.

Comment: That was that ! Thanks. It would be nice for Firebug to display this font property, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is set in CSS - in a way:

```
.ac_results li {
    font: menu;
}
```

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand):

> 'font'
>   Value:    [ [ <'font-style'> ||
>   <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]?
>   <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]?
>   <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon |
>   **menu** | message-box | small-caption |
>   status-bar | inherit

`menu` is then defined as:

> The font used in menus (e.g., dropdown menus and menu lists).

Comment: Thanks! I missed the font definition - would be nice if Firebug displayed it! Thanks for the spec reference too, that's great.